# Stop words changed negative review to positive ones. What is a good way to remove stop words in text summarization process?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, stop-words

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPFai.png)I try to remove stop words (English) from two columns in a data frame. See screenshot. However, I found that after applying this process, the meaning of the review was changed. e.g. Not recommend was changed to recommended. What is the best way to remove stop words while remaining the idea of the original text unchanged? This is my code and results:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))

df['Text_after_removed_stopwords'] = df['Text'].apply(lambda x: ' 
'.join([word for word in x.split() if word not in (stop)]))
print()
print('###Text after removed 
stopwords###'+'\n'+df['Text_after_removed_stopwords'][1])
print()
print('###Text before removed stopwords###'+'\n'+ df['Text'][1])
print()
df['Summary_after_removed_stopwords'] = df['Summary'].apply(lambda 
x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word not in (stop)]))
print('###Summary after removed stopwords###'+ ' 
\n'+df['Summary_after_removed_stopwords'][1])
print()
print('###Summary before removed stopwords###'+'\n'+df['Summary'][ 
1])


###Text after removed stopwords###
product arrived labeled jumbo salted peanutsthe peanuts actually 
small sized unsalted sure error vendor intended represent product 
jumbo

###Text before removed stopwords###
product arrived labeled as jumbo salted peanutsthe peanuts were 
actually small sized unsalted not sure if this was an error or if 
the vendor intended to represent the product as jumbo

###Summary after removed stopwords###
advertised

###Summary before removed stopwords###
not as advertised
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing words from text inherently changes the vector representations, which I assume your summary application is using. The best thing to do would be to create your own custom stop words list. Also keep in mind that for some texts the change in meaning will be undesired, but that these may be outliers!